# remove white border around container using viewport size

Tags: html, css

I have a white border around my entire website right now that I am trying to get rid of. I looked it up online and found several sources that all say to set `margin: 0;` but when I did this, it is not removing the white border. I suspect it has something to do with using view width and view height instead of pixels or percentages, so how can I remove the white border without changing the width and height from using the viewport size?

```css
.container {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: purple;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
</div>
```

Comment: What are you adding the margin property to?  I created a codepen with your code and added ```margin:0```, and it removed the white border.  Use the * selector to target everything on the page  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xBGyxV

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you have to set the `margin: 0` property on body not on the div container, hope it helped

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
* {margin: 0; padding: 0}
```

I recommend checking basic universal css boilerplate